# Recover photos from iPhone with broken screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, screen

My girlfriend recently dropped her iPhone 4S in water. She let it sit in rice for 2 days, but the screen was still broken. However, the phone was still functional, as she could hear Siri working with the home button. The thing is, she needs photos taken off the device. Normally this would be easy since she has no passcode, but my fear is it will need the iPhone to press "Trust" on the prompt that comes up.

Any ideas how to get them off while getting around this prompt?

Comment: Has the phone ever been backed up to iCloud or to any computer / iTunes?

Comment: This "trust" thing is really annoying and makes no sense. What, like someone's going to secretly connect my iPhone to his Mac without taking my iPhone?

Comment: The trust thing is not without reason. Bogus charging spots exist and could install unwanted software onto your phone if you did not have to "trust" a data line. If you don't trust it, the phone will charge but not accept data.

Comment: Nonone knows any answer to this question?  been 5 yrs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone 4 water damage - how to recover data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63341/iphone-4-water-damage-how-to-recover-data)